# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException inside Android SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, indexoutofboundsexception, newrelic

I am using newrelic for crash reports. In newrelic crash list I can see a exception inside Android SharedPreferenceImpl. Can someone help me debug the crash cause ?
crash:

```
    EXCEPTION java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
LOCATION FastXmlSerializer.java line 70 in FastXmlSerializer.append()
TIME Today, xx:yy
MESSAGE length=0; index=699
```

Huawei Device (HUAWEI Y320-U30) Android 4.2.2 (C307B600)

Below is complete stack trace provided by newrelic

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=699
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.append()(FastXmlSerializer.java:70)
at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.startTag()(FastXmlSerializer.java:335)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml()(XmlUtils.java:468)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml()(XmlUtils.java:245)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml()(XmlUtils.java:185)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile()(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:598)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800()(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run()(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker()(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run()(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access index 699 of an array that has 0 elements. Can you include the code that you think is throwing the error?

Comment: @ryguy I dont know where in my code this crash is happening ? I have got this stacktrace from newrelic.

Comment: Not sure anyone will be able to help without having any code to look at... Where in your code are you using fastXmlSerializer?

Comment: @ryguy I did file search in my whole workspace I didn't find any use of FastXmlSerializer inside my code. May be some external jar using it.

Comment: Hmm that is very weird.. what about sharedPreferences? Any code where you are using them?

Comment: @ryguy Yes I am using shared preferences in my code. But I am not sure where this crash is happening exactly.

Comment: @BrajeshKumar did you found any solution to this?

Comment: The crash is in the Android platform that is using that XML library to parse shared preferences.